# Codeigniter - Routing with Slug without showing controller name in URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

I have Implemented Slug Functionality in My Website From which i can access webpage via http://www.example.com/controller_name/slug_name
But now i want to access that webpage without displaying controller_name in URL. Just Like WordPress Slug Functionality.

I want to access webpage directly after Domain name by slug via http://www.example.com/slug_name url.
How can i do that in Codeigniter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This effect can achieve it as you describe what you want in application/config/routes.php file. https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

```
$route['world-travel-locations']  = 'videos/index';
```

Comment: But using URI Routing  i have to define it for all pages but i want function code that will directly redirect to webpage using slug only. because this URI routing goes tedious if i have 200 controller page in my site.

Comment: you didn't understood my question yet.. i dont want unique slug i want to access whole my project webpages by www.sitename.com/slug by hiding controller  http://www.web-and-development.com/codeigniter-remove-index-php-minimize-url link gave me some idea but this is not working. so i want alternate solution of it. to remove controllers and method of all my webpages.

Comment: And this >> http://vikku.info/programming/php/create-unique-clean-url-slug-for-codeigniter-and-core-php.htm